# Base64 string to image src in html FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I stored an image as base64 string in firebase. Later, i tried to retrieve the string and show image in a popup window using jquery mobile. I'm getting **!!!FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION!!!** error when i assign

```
img_id.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_string;
```

Comment: i am having the same issue. works in chrome and breaks in IE. I believe it has to do with the size of the string being assigned to the src attribute. have any luck with it?

Comment: Instead of displaying the image in popup window, I redirected to new page and tried to display the image in that new page. And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of img_id.src = ...

assuming img_id is the string representation of the img tag id:

```
$("#" + img_id).attr('src',  "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_string );
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a fiddle that reproduces the problem?